# Problems with creating a survivalobject in R using the `survival` package

Tags: r, survival, survminer

I am currently working on a Kaplan-Meier-Plot in R using the `survival` package and I am planning on creating and designing the plot using the `survminer` package afterwards.

The data I have is from an excel table:
`data <- read_excel("worksheet".xlsx", na = "NA", sheet = 1)` is what I used to import the data.
The structure of the data (I manipulated it a bit before) is as following:

> gropd_df [37 × 5] (S3: grouped_df/tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
> $ n         : num [1:37] 1 1 1 1 15 40 5 6 1 311 ...
> $ Rec       : num [1:37] 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 105 ...
> $ nonRec    : num [1:37] 1 1 1 1 15 39 5 6 1 206 ...
> $ time      : num [1:37] 3 6 6 6 7.5 8 8 8.5 9 9.9...

I now want to create a Survivalobject using `Surv()` and then later the kaplan-meier estimate with `survfit()` from the Survivalobject:
`so <- Surv(data$time, data$Rec)`.

The variable `n` stands for the number of people observed in a study, `time` stands for the time after an operation (time = 0 on operations day) where the patients had a follow-up examination of their disease. If the disease did come back after the operation (determined in the follow-up examination), the patient was counted in `Rec`, if the disease did not reoccur, he/she was counted as `nonRec`.

As you can see, the events are not displayed as `time` and `status` with status being "0" or "1", but as `time` and number of people being "0" (`nonRec`) and number of people being "1" (`Rec`). Therefore, creating the survivalobject above does (obviously) not work out how I want:

> so <- Surv(data$time, data$Rec)
> Warning message:
> In Surv(data$time, data$Rec) : Invalid status value, converted to NA

Does anyone know a smart solution to solve this? Changing the data manually does not work out given the size of the data. Also, I am sorry if this question may seem dumb to you but I startet using R just a few weeks ago and I`m by far not a pro in using it..
Help would be very welcome, thanks for reading :)

Update following @jpsmith comment (hope this is right):

```
dput(FUP)
structure(list(n = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 15, 40, 5, 6, 1, 311, 20, 7, 
5, 60, 25, 25, 62, 228, 1, 12, 29, 24, 86, 41, 200, 5, 3, 30, 
3, 30, 237, 41, 162, 10, 14, 27, 1), Rec = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
0, 0, 0, 105, 1, 0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 6, 6, 0, 1, 9, 2, 15, 3, 22, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 4, 23, 10, 0, 0, 4, 2, 0), nonRec = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 
15, 39, 5, 6, 1, 206, 19, 7, 3, 59, 25, 25, 56, 222, 1, 11, 20, 
22, 71, 38, 178, 5, 3, 29, 3, 26, 214, 31, 162, 10, 10, 25, 1
), fuptime = c(3, 6, 6, 6, 7.5, 8, 8, 8.5, 9, 9.9, 10, 10, 12, 
12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12.3, 13.9, 14, 15.2, 18, 21, 24.2, 
25, 28, 30, 30, 35.3, 36, 36, 36, 48.6, 66), operation3 = c("12-laser", 
"12-laser", "12-laser", "12-laser", "12-laser", "12-laser", "12-laser", 
"12-laser", "12-laser", "12-laser", "12-laser", "12-laser", "12-laser", 
"12-laser", "12-laser", "12-laser", "12-laser", "12-laser", "12-laser", 
"12-laser", "12-laser", "12-laser", "12-laser", "12-laser", "12-laser", 
"12-laser", "12-laser", "12-laser", "12-laser", "12-laser", "12-laser", 
"12-laser", "12-laser", "12-laser", "12-laser", "12-laser", "12-laser"
)), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-37L), groups = structure(list(fuptime = c(3, 6, 7.5, 8, 8.5, 
9, 9.9, 10, 12, 12.3, 13.9, 14, 15.2, 18, 21, 24.2, 25, 28, 30, 
35.3, 36, 48.6, 66), .rows = structure(list(1L, 2:4, 5L, 6:7, 
    8L, 9L, 10L, 11:12, 13:20, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 
    27L, 28L, 29L, 30:31, 32L, 33:35, 36L, 37L), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
"vctrs_vctr", "list"))), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -23L), .drop = TRUE))
```

Comment: Welcome! Could you edit your question to include the output of `dput(gropd_df)`? Thanks!

Comment: Your problem is that your data frame contains summary level data.  A Kaplan-Meier analysis requires participant-level data.  So you need to convert your data from one-observation-per-event-time to one-observation-per-particpant.  `tidyr::uncount` is an obvious way to do this.

Comment: @jpsmith meant that we need to see your data.  You refer to both `data` and `gropd_df` in your question, and we don't know which is correct. Whatever the name of the object containing your data, pass it to `dput()` and post the output in your question.

Comment: I know that's your problem.  I've given you a possible solution: `tidyr::uncount()`.  But I can't demonstrate it to you because you have not provided any test data in an easily accessible form.  You maximise your chance of getting a useful answer if you provide a minimal reproducible example. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) may help.

Comment: @Limey Im really sorry, didnt read your comment fully. I hope I now provided the right data, but if ´tidyr::uncount´ isnt too complicated Ill see into it when I have enough time and try to solve it myself, I dont want to make any unnecessary inconveniences for you so ill give an update later. Thank you for answering this fast!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I said in my comment, `uncount()` is a good way to convert your data to one-observation-per-participant.  For example:

```
library(tidyverse)

fup1 <- fup %>% 
  uncount(n) %>% 
  mutate(Status = ifelse(Rec == 0, 0, 1)) %>% 
  select(-Rec, -nonRec) %>%
  ungroup() 

fup1
# A tibble: 1,770 × 3
   fuptime operation3 Status
     <dbl> <chr>       <dbl>
 1     3   12-laser        0
 2     6   12-laser        0
 3     6   12-laser        0
 4     6   12-laser        0
 5     7.5 12-laser        0
 6     7.5 12-laser        0
 7     7.5 12-laser        0
 8     7.5 12-laser        0
 9     7.5 12-laser        0
10     7.5 12-laser        0
# … with 1,760 more rows
```

Note that I've converted your `Rec` and `nonRec` columns to a single indicator column, `Status`.

Now it's easy to fit your Kaplan-Meier model:

```
library(survival)

survfit(Surv(fuptime, Status) ~ operation3, data=fup1)
Call: survfit(formula = Surv(fuptime, Status) ~ operation3, data = fup1)

        n events median 0.95LCL 0.95UCL
[1,] 1770   1497     14      14    15.2
```